# In (android) Realm how do i sort a list based on a column by column multiplication?

Tags: android, realm

I got a realm object like so

```
public class MyItem extends RealmObject {
public Product product;
public double amount;
}

public class Product extends RealmObject {
public double price;
}
```

I would like to sort my realm list by MyItem(product.price*amount) ascending. How is this possible with Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyItem extends RealmObject {
    private double price;
    private double amount;
    private double total;

    // getters for price/amount

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.total = price * amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.total = price * amount;
    }
}
```

Then

```
realm.where(MyItem.class).findAllSorted("total", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

---

EDIT: With the modification, same rules apply.

```
public class MyItem extends RealmObject {
    private Product product;
    private double amount;

    private double totalPrice;

    void updateTotalPrice() {
        if(product == null) {
            totalPrice = 0;
        } else {
            totalPrice = amount * product.getPrice();
        }
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
        updateTotalPrice();
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        updateTotalPrice();
    }
}

public class Product extends RealmObject {
    private double price;

    @LinkingObjects("product")
    private final RealmResults<MyItem> items = null;

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
        if(items != null) { // updates to existing object should happen only via managed objects!
            for(MyItem item : items) {
                item.updateTotalPrice();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
realm.where(MyItem.class).findAllSorted("totalPrice", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Ah! Thats it. I was thinking along those lines but would have implemented it in a terrible way. My problem is a slight bit more complex though. Sorry i edited the question. Now you may see my dilemma, the getters and setters arent easily accomplished for nested objects

Comment: Yeah thats exactly it. My product has a huge amount of other things like weight, color, size, etc etc, but could you give an example of that uni-directional link. That sounds like something straight outta star wars bro

Comment: I actually realized that I think I understand your use-case and will need a different approach. Also it's 3 am but i'll put this thing together then put myself to rest

Comment: haha take some rest bro, its 3am here too :) i should do the same. Thanks for your effort though. Speak tomorrow dude, ty!

Comment: Great solution bro, only problem is if the Product price updates frequently which unfortunately in my case it does (Forex :) ) then the parent MyItem doesnt update its totalPrice and the order is not correct anymore. :/ This is driving me nuts

Comment: In that case you'll need a 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT feature but i'll edit the solution with that. Although I'm starting to think I'm just hacking at this point.

Comment: Thanks bro! I appreciate all your help. Youve helped me before too. Absolute legend.. I might as well ask this now before you post your solution though. If i use version 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT features would you consider it stable enough to put into my app release next week?

Comment: Realm-Core 2.8.0 had such bug fixes for encrypted Realms by which I'd consider the snapshot more stable than the current release, and no other change in Realm 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT seemed like it could have broken things.

Comment: Ok great, Cheers dude! Ill read up on the snapshots and how to implement. Have a good day panda-man!

Comment: Hold on, I've just remembered that `@LinkingObjects` works from 3.1.0 and above, it's just **queries** across linking objects that was added with 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT. So this solution is actually compatible with 3.1.0+. Whoops :D man i'm tired today

Comment: Ill give it a go and let you know! I got the latest 3.3.1 version. Must say im loving this over SQL, you guys are doing a fantastic job. Keep it up

Comment: oh I'm just a random passing community member, not an official Realm person. Backlink queries are gonna be awesome though, so I agree :D

Comment: Just to get back to you bro, although you already know this, it worked :) And i just learnt about LinkingObjects. Very usefull. My power grows stronger! haha